# How can I delete The black border on that textbox?

Tags: html, css

How Can I delete the [black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjkNE.png) when clicking on any input??

Here is my HTML

```
            <div class="info">
                <input class="forms" type="text" placeholder="First Name.">
                <input class="forms" type="email" placeholder="Email Adress.">
                <input class="forms" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number (optional)">
                <input id="submitbtn" type="button" value="SUBMIT MESSAGE">

            </div>
```

AND here is css

```css
    .forms {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: blue;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    width: 440px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    }
    .forms::placeholder {
    color: rgba(0, 41, 255, 0.42);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code you your CSS and your problem will be solved

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that disabling an input element's outline is not recommended as it hinders accessibility. The outline property is there for a reason - providing users with a clear indication of keyboard focus. For further go through this link http://outlinenone.com/